# Year, month, week, day, hour, minute, second abbreviation in Italian

Tags: abbreviations

I'm writing some code that turns duration into human-readable text. And I wish to do it **correctly**. Below are example cases, please point out the mistakes in Italian one. (I don't have any Italian knowledge)

English:

| Long | Mid | Short |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a second | 1 sec | 1s |
| 2 seconds | 2 sec | 2s |
| a minute | 1 min | 1m |
| 6 minutes | 6 min | 6m |
| an hour | 1 hr | 1h |
| 9 hours | 9 hr | 9h |
| a day | 1 day | 1d |
| 6 days | 6 day | 6d |
| a week | 1 wk | 1wk |
| 2 weeks | 2 wk | 2wk |
| a month | 1 mo | 1mo |
| 3 months | 3 mo | 3mo |
| a year | 1 yr | 1y |
| 7 years | 7 yr | 6y |

---

Italian:

Bolded texts are ones I'm not sure of. Is dot (.) after abbreviation necessary? Should there be space before short form (`1 s` or `1s`)?

| Long | Mid | Short |
| --- | --- | --- |
| un secondo | **1 sec** | **1 s** |
| 2 secondi | **2 sec** | **2 s** |
| un minuto | **1 min** | **1 m** |
| 6 minuti | **6 min** | **6 m** |
| un'ora | **un'ora** | **1 h** |
| 9 ore | **9 ore** | **9 h** |
| un giorno | **1 g.** | **1 g.** |
| 6 giorni | **6 gg.** | **6 gg.** |
| una settimana | **1 set.** | **1 set.** |
| 2 settimane | **2 set.** | **2 set.** |
| un mese | **1 mese** | **1 mese** |
| 3 mesi | **3 mesi** | **3 mesi** |
| un anno | **1 anno** | **1 anno** |
| 7 anni | **7 anni** | **6 anni** |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- All "long" forms should probably use alphabetical representation of numbers rather than numerical (i.e. "due" instead of "2").
- I would replace the "mid" form for `ora` from `un'ora` to `1 ora`.
- I would replace the "mid" form for `giorno` from `1 g.` to `1 giorno`.
- I would differentiate the "mid" and "short" form for `6 giorni`. For "mid",  I would use `6 giorni`, while for the "short" form `6 gg.` is correct. The long form should probably use the alphabetical "sei" rather than 6.
- I would replace the abbreviation for settimana `set.` with `sett.`. We like double consonants in cases like these.
- For "short" of mesi, depending on context, I would find acceptable both `m.` (which is still different from `m` of minutes, no dot) or `ms.` (although, depending on context, this latter could be confused with the abbreviation for "millisecondi").
- For "short" of anni, you can use `a.`.